# How to run a remote linux script(s) using JSch?

Tags: java, jsch

Currently I am able to establish an SSH session using JSch but I am not able to run a bunch of scripts from the terminal with the freshly established SSH session.

I am not getting what methods I can use to trigger a START script which triggers other scripts as required.

Please help me out with a way which I can use to run the remote script automatically using JSch. I need to run it non interactively so that I can use it in my automation framework.

Following code does the current task described above:

```
    Session session;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

        session.setPassword(passw);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect(); 
        Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        prefer channel.send(command);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        channel.connect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance for all the inputs,

Narayan

Comment: Have you tried Google? For [example](http://www.journaldev.com/246/java-program-to-run-shell-commands-on-ssh-enabled-system), you might also want to take a look at the [exec](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html) example found in the source...

Comment: Thank you.Had not tried exec. It seems exec works the way I wanted to be but I see some more problems with my current setting.

With exec I am successfully able to trigger the required script but after some particular duration (which is configured in the script), another script gets kicked off and it kills this script. After it kills this script I am getting exit status 137!

After the killScript, there has to be some more processing which I am not able to execute with this exec. How can that be handled?

Comment: In the example you shared, I can see how to execute one script. I tried different ways but did not get a way to run multiple commands. It would be helpful if I could get how to run multiple commands using exec. This might provide a workaround to the possible cause.

Comment: Presumably, you need to create a new `Channel` for each script

Comment: I tried it out but somehow I guess I am missing the right order. Anyways for now I am deferring it.

I took out the kill command for that particular script and it seems to be working now! Thanks for all your inputs. :)

Comment: Use 'NOHUP' before your command, and a space and '&' ampersand after your command.  This will execute the script in the background, so its success/failure/duration will not affect your java program.